# Clarification - Custom Method in String.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to add one custom method using `String.proptotype` for comparing the string. Look at the following code

```
 String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
        return this === val;
 }
```

I am comparing the two values is equals or not. Look at the following snippet.

```js
function getSelectValue() {
         var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
         if(selectedValue==="stackoverflow") {
              document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
         } else {
              document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
         }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
    <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
    <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

The above snippet is working fine and compare the selected value and display it in the textbox. I tried to change the line `selectedValue==="stackoverflow"` with my custom method `compare`, then it is not working. It always falls into the else part. Look at the below snippet.

```js
function getSelectValue() {
        String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
              return this === val;
        }
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
        if(selectedValue.compare("stackoverflow")) {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
        }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
      <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here? Please clarify.

Comment: What's the console.log showing?

Comment: @TahaPaksu No error in the console.log

Comment: If you do this `return this == val;` instead, it will work. The use of only 2 equal sign will do an _auto type conversion_. With 3 you'll match an object with a string

Comment: @LGSon that is a cool solution. working perfectly. So == will do the same like `.toString()` or `.valueOf()`. Is that correct?

Comment: The `==` does a type conversion, if needed, so in this case it is similar to `toString()`, the `valueOf()` returns the primitive value of the specified object.

Comment: @LGSon thanks for your clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, and I decided to add it as an answer, to show yet another solution.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you think it's right. We are expecting this from you. Don't just ask and go away.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.valueOf` (*this represents the entire `String` object, you need to compare its value*)

```
String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
      return this.valueOf() === val;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function getSelectValue() {
        String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
              return this.valueOf() === val;
        }
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
        if(selectedValue.compare("stackoverflow")) {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
        }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
      <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

Comment: `this` represents the entire String Object

Answer (score 1):

Use this.toString() to compare.

```js
function getSelectValue() {
        String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
                      return this.toString() === val;
        }
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
        if(selectedValue.compare("stackoverflow")) {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
        }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
      <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

The string shows like this in the console:

[image]

And it's not equal to "stackoverflow". I think you need to call ".toString()" or something to achieve this.

```js
function getSelectValue() {
  String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
    return this.toString() === val;
  }
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
  if (selectedValue.compare("stackoverflow")) {
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
      <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answers, worth mentioning is the identity operator `===`.

As it needs the two values being evaluated to be of the same type, or else it will return false, one could instead use the equal operator `==`.

Their main difference is that the `==` does a type conversion, if needed, and will in this case be yet another option.

Stack snippet

```js
function getSelectValue() {
        String.prototype.compare = function(val) {
              return this == val;
        }
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
        if(selectedValue.compare("stackoverflow")) {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Overflow";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("name").value = "Stack Community";
        }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
      <option value="stackoverflow">overflow</option>
      <option value="stackcommunity">Community</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```js
a = new String('foo');
b = new String('foo');

console.log(a === b);       // false
console.log(a === "foo");   // false
```

Both logs are `false` because when you use `===`,

1. two objects are never equal to each other
2. a primitive (like `"foo"`) is never equal to an object

When you define `equals` like you did, it never returns `true` for the same reasons: if the other value is an object, rule #1 applies, if it's a literal string, #2 applies.

```js
String.prototype.equals = function(other) {
  return this === other;
}

a = new String('foo');
b = new String('foo');

console.log(a.equals(b));      // false
console.log(a.equals("foo"));  // false
```

A better way to define `String.equals` is to check the type of the other value and take different actions, depending on the type:

- if `other` is a string primitive, demote `this` to a primitive and compare
- if `other` is a String object, demote both `this` and `other`, and compare
- otherwise, return false. Alternatively, you might want to add some logic to compare strings to numbers or empty strings to nulls.

```js
String.prototype.equals = function (other) {

    if (typeof other === 'string')
        return String(this) === other;

    if (other instanceof String)
        return String(this) === String(other);

    return false;
}

a = new String('foo');
b = new String('foo');

console.log(a.equals(b));      // true
console.log(a.equals('foo'));  // true
```

In this form, our `String.equals` even starts to be useful, because

- unlike `===`, it can compare string primitives and string objects
- unlike `==`, it doesn't rely on Javascript's vague coercion rules

Hope this helps.